# JQuery, how to select elements based on their position relative to siblings?

Tags: jquery, html, dom, css-selectors

```
<img class="a"/>
<img class="a"/>
<img class="a"/>
<img class="b"/>
<img class="a"/>
<img class="a"/>
<img class="c"/>
```

I don't want to select all `.a`. But I want to select all `.a` which precede elements other than `.a` - so in this case, I want to select the 3rd and the 6th `img`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select images with class `a` whose immediate sibling is an image without class `a`
2. Select the previous element (the image)
3. Do something:

```
$('img.a + :not("img.a")').prev().addClass('foo')
```

```js
$('img.a + :not("img.a")').prev().addClass('foo')
```

```css
.foo {
  border: 5px solid #faa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="a" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100" />
<img class="a" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100" />
<img class="a" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100" />
<img class="b" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100" />
<img class="a" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100" />
<img class="a" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100" />
<img class="c" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100" />
```